# PHP submitted checkbox value is a string or a boolean?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

Do you guys know when you submit a form via PHP, is the form checkbox value being treated as the string "true" or boolean true?  Assuming my checkbox value attribute was set to "true".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit a checkbox, the value will be whatever you set the value attribute as, and will be a string when PHP parses the form data and populates `$_REQUEST` and friends.

If you don't specify a value in the form, then browsers default to `"on"`, not `"true"` (this is being made [standard behaviour in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-value-default-on)).

Comment: Just wondering, what if it's an integer? Will it still "be interpreted" as a string?

Comment: It can't be anything but a string. It might a string that happens to look like an integer, but it is still a string. (Although PHP will usually type convert).

Comment: That's what I was thinking (and was too lazy to fire up WinSCP to test...). Just wanted to confirm. Thanks! `:D`

Comment: Ok, so I decided I'd test it anyways: http://jfcoder.com/test/formfieldtype.php Result: `string(1) "1"`.